# Enviar correo API REST Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

quiero hacer un servicio rest con spring boot para enviar correo,pero tengo problemas con el paso de los parámetros desde postman:

service:

```
 @Service
    public class SendMailService {

        @Autowired
        private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

        public void sendMail(String from, String to, String subject, String body) {

            SimpleMailMessage mail = new SimpleMailMessage();

            mail.setFrom(from);
            mail.setTo(to);
            mail.setSubject(subject);
            mail.setText(body);

            javaMailSender.send(mail);
        }
    }
```

controller:

```
@RestController
public class SendMailController {

    @Autowired
    private SendMailService mailService;

     @RequestMapping(value = "/sendMail", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String sendMail(@RequestParam(value = "name") String name, @RequestParam(value = "mail") String mail, @RequestParam(value = "subject") String subject, @RequestParam(value = "body") String body){

        String message = body +"\n\n Datos de contacto: " + "\nNombre: " + name + "\nE-mail: " + mail;
        mailService.sendMail("correoorigen@gmail.com",mail,subject,message);

        return "correo enviado";
    }
}
```

llamada desde postman:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

error dice que no se está pasando la variable name

favor su ayuda.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Estás mandando un texto JSON en el cuerpo de la petición POST, no estás enviando parámetros en la URL (que es lo que se busca con la anotación `@RequestParam`). En este caso te recomiendo lo siguiente:

### Opción A (recomendada)

1. Crea una clase para recibir los datos (Spring se encargará de crear y rellenar la instancia):

```
class MailForm {

   private String name, mail, body, subject;

   //getters y setters públicos
}
```

2. Modifica la firma de tu método en el controlador para usar `@RequestBody`:

```
@RestController
public class SendMailController {

    @Autowired
    private SendMailService mailService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/sendMail", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String sendMail(@RequestBody MailForm form){

        String message = form.getBody() +"\n\n Datos de contacto: " +
                "\nNombre: " + form.getName() + "\nE-mail: " + form.getMail();

        mailService.sendMail("correoorigen@gmail.com",mail,subject,message);

        return "correo enviado";
    }
}
```

De este modo recibirás los datos que buscas de un modo sencillo.

### Opción B

Realiza la llamada con postman añadiendo en la URL los datos:

```
.../sendMail?name=minombre&subject=prueba&body=correo%20desde%20Spring&email=correo%40gmail.com
```

Lo que es problemático si el campo body es muy largo, porque la URL tiene una longitud máxima de unos 3000 caracteres y necesitas escapar muchos de los caracteres que no se admiten como parte de una URL.

Comment: Creo que la opción A sería la más adecuada en este caso.

Comment: Por eso es la que recomiendo :)

Comment: la opción A anduvo perfecto. Gracias